# mat-select possibly formControlName problem

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have different question types and I'm trying to create a new one: a dropdown list with images. To do this, I use Angular Material. When an option is selected, I'm normally able to show an image on the screen. I know that this part works because I used it in several different locations inside my code. I actually reuse almost everything, here's my classic dropdown list (dropdown-list.html):

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="form-groups">
  <label [attr.for]="'q_dd_' + question.id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label question-title" id="title"
    [ngClass]="{'disabled-text': form.get(question.id).disabled}">{{question.label}}</label>
  <app-help-image [question]="question" class="col-sm-1"></app-help-image>
  <div class="field-position">
    <select [id]="'q_dd_' + question.id" [formControlName]="question.id" [compareWith]="optionComparer"
      class="custom-select form-control input-style">
      <option></option>
      <option *ngFor="let opt of (question.rule.outputs$ | async)" [ngValue]="opt" class="input-style">{{opt.label}}</option>
    </select>
    <app-validation-messages [question]="question"></app-validation-messages>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the dropdown list that I'm trying to create(dropdown-list-with-images.html):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label [attr.for]="'q_ddi_' + question.id" [ngClass]="{'disabled-text': form.get(question.id).disabled}">{{question.label}}</mat-label>
        <mat-select  [id]="'q_ddi_' + question.id" [formControlName]="question.id" [compareWith]="optionComparer" (selectionChange)="onRoomChange($event)">
            <mat-select-trigger>
                <span *ngIf="selectedOption">
                    <img [src]="selectedOption.fullImageUrl">
                    {{selectedOption.label}} 
                </span>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option></mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of (question.rule.outputs$ | async)" [value]="opt" >
                <img [src]="opt.fullImageUrl" [alt]="opt.label">
                {{opt.label}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

So as you can see I'm basically trying to do the same thing with Angular Material but it doesn't seem to work. Even though I'm sure, I suspect the error is caused by `formControlName`. Am I missing something?

My .ts:

```
export class DropDownListWithImagesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() question: QuestionDropDownImagesState;

  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  selectedOption: any;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onRoomChange(event){
    this.selectedOption = event.value;
  }

  optionComparer(opt1: RuleOutputState, opt2: RuleOutputState): boolean {
    let bool = false;
    if (opt1 != null && opt2 != null) {
      bool = opt1.id === opt2.id;
    } else if (!opt1 && !opt2) {
      bool = true;
    }
    return bool;
  }

}
```

Comment: What are the error messages, if any, in the console?

Comment: One question I have is why does your mat-select, and also regular select, have an empty option?

Comment: @SomeStudent there are no error messages in the console which makes that much harder to find where the problem is coming from. I posted the question to see if I'm missing something in the HTML because I know for sure that it's the cause because I tried different things on the same file and it works perfectly with everything else. When I start using angular material controls, that's where the problem begins.

Comment: @SomeStudent I don't want a default value, the empty option gives me an empty field to start. I will try to take it off but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @SomeStudent I confirm that the empty option is not the cause

Answer (score 0):

Posting this possible answer here instead of in the comments, but have you tried using a formGroupName?

I assume that in your definition of your form, you probably have something like this:

```
question: this.fb.group({...})
```

Where this.fb is the form builder defined in the constructor. As such try in your HTML the following:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
   <ng-container formGroupName="question">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label [attr.for]="'q_ddi_' + question.id" [ngClass]="{'disabled-text': form.get(question.id).disabled}">{{question.label}}</mat-label>
        <mat-select  [id]="'q_ddi_' + question.id" [formControlName]="id" [compareWith]="optionComparer" (selectionChange)="onRoomChange($event)">
            <mat-select-trigger>
                <span *ngIf="selectedOption">
                    <img [src]="selectedOption.fullImageUrl">
                    {{selectedOption.label}} 
                </span>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option></mat-option>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of (question.rule.outputs$ | async)" [value]="opt" >
                <img [src]="opt.fullImageUrl" [alt]="opt.label">
                {{opt.label}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
   </ng-container>
</form>
```

One question I do still have is that in your first example, the none mat select, your formGroup is defined as part of a regular div, whereas in the mat-select version it is actually wrapped as its own `<form>` element, is this on purpose?

Comment: I updated the question with my .ts class, as you can see ```question``` itself is not a form controller. The form controllers are constructed using the question ids. And the reason I used ```form``` is because I saw a solution on the internet and tried to apply it but putting a ```div``` instead doesn't change anything.